# Getting size and comparing attribute value from ArrayList in other class

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to create a method which creates a result for a athlete in a competition. I have an ArrayList with the athletes in another class and now I want this method to be able to find the size of the ArrayList and also compare one int attribute of every Athlete with the input number. This is what I have so far, Im really stuck. So my quetions to you are: How do I get my for loop to see the size of the ArrayList athletes? and what is a proper way to check whether or not the input has a matching athlete in the ArrayList(I want it to print out if there is no match)? Thank you

```
    public class ResultList {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();

public ResultList() {
     ArrayList<Athlete> temp = new AthleteList().getArrayList();
}

void addResult() {
    int competetionNumber;
    System.out.print("What is the athletes competetionnumber?");
    competetionNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < athletes.size(); i++) {

    }
}
}
```

Other class with the Athlete ArrayList:

```
    public class AthleteList {
ArrayList<Athlete> athletes = new ArrayList<Athlete>();
public AthleteList () {

}
     public ArrayList<Athlete> getArrayList() {
     return athletes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a variable that points to the AthleteList class. Then you can see that in the addResult method you just get the ArrayList from the AthleteList and call size() on it and iterate over the Athletes and check the completionNumber(You didn't post the Athlete class so I'm assuming there is a completionNumber property). I create a matched variable to hold on to the matched Athlete. After the loop I check to see if one matched and print out the result.

Hope this helps.

```
public class ResultList
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();
    AthleteList athleteList;

    public ResultList()
    {
        athleteList = new AthleteList();
    }

    void addResult()
    {
        int competetionNumber;
        System.out.print("What is the athletes competetionnumber?");
        competetionNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextInt();

        Athlete matched = null;
        List<Athlete> athletes = athleteList.getArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < athletes.size(); i++)
        {
            if(athlete.completionNumber == completionNumber)
            {
                //you found a match!!
                matched = athlete;
            }
        }

        if(matched == null)
        {
            System.out.println("No Match Found for " + completionNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Found match: " + matched.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:
Not sure you need the AthleteList class. It's just holding an ArrayList. If that's all that class will ever do then I suggest you just using an ArrayList. It will make your code cleaner.